# Hyper-V CentOS 5.11 kernel: journal commit I/O error

Tags: hyper-v, centos5, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, hyper-v-server-2012

Running CentOS i386 5.11 with Hyper-V I have found an issue where a newly installed (and updated via yum) box has corrupted itself the first warning was in the SSH session kernel: journal commit I/O error now the CentOS guest wont boot.

The physical hardware is a DELL R710, PERC H700. No errors on the DELL OpenManage software for the physical drives.

It is running Windows Server 2012 R2, everything seems fine with the physical box Windows operates fine (no crashing, up-time for months, good IO performance between drives).

Is this an incompatibility with Hyper-V and CentOS 5?

Or something more deep rooted and concerning with the hardware and if so any reason this is not showing in the storage controller logs?

Comment: What virtual machine version (generation 1 / 2) did you deploy with? I've had a lot of trouble with gen 2 and Linux systems in the past, not sure whether there's full synthetic driver support in place yet...

Comment: Gen1... Reinstalled the VM and this time haven't ran yun update has been fine for days. A second gen2 centos 7 VM on same hardware is fine. No errors on RAID hardware from DELL openmanage. The centos 5.11 goes unresponsive to iput via the Hyper-V console from time to time but SSH is fine. Very strange